# Set up to simulate failures for a dozen of computers in a WAN

Tags: networking, virtual, simulation, robustness

For testing reasons I need to simulate a set up with a few up to a dozen machines that can fail anytime in a LAN (or WAN) that may fail too.

How would you do it using free/open software?
Is there any virtualization solution that allows to kill/reboot machines and bring online/offline (virtually) their connections?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably start with something like Oracle VirtualBox, running a dozen workstation VMs.

While you are running your tests, you can programatically pause/resume your VMs from the command line to simulate system hangs (e.g. for a Windows VirtualBox install):

```
C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox>VBoxManage list vms
"CentOS 6.4 (x86_64)" {fb99d1b3-9ff8-4149-9726-635e85996d34}

C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox>VBoxManage controlvm fb99d1b3-9ff8-4149-9726-
635e85996d34 pause

C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox>VBoxManage controlvm fb99d1b3-9ff8-4149-9726-
635e85996d34 resume
```

-- ab1

Comment: That sounds good, I think with the command line you could also plug and unplug the virtual NICs. Do you have any advice on how I could set up complex network topologies?

For example having a not fully connected network, and trying to simulate network splits, and so.

Comment: Yes, looks like you can control the link state of the NICs, using "setlinkstate" sub-command (http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-controlvm).  Regarding your second point, if you are talking about physically multi-homed VMs (multiple vNICs), then it probably warrants a separate question as it is a bit more complicated.  Cheers!